# Continue downloading files starting from the URL where it stops: WGET

Tags: wget

I want to download files using **wget**. The maximum depth is up to 3. Now, I know that there is a big possibility that the files in the URL will be updated.
Is there a way that these updated/modified files will be the only ones to be downloaded?

For example, day 1: I'll run the Python script that will download all files from a particular site.

Day 2: I'll run the same script, expecting that it will download all UPDATED files ONLY.

What parameter do I need to add to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-N` (`--timestamping`) option. For example, `wget -N www.google.com.`